# I try to give default pixel size of image when i insert a new product

Tags: php, mysql

I give there only `UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE` But i want to give default size of pixels. Help me

```
  <?php
    // Upload configs.
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads');
    define('UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE', 5485760); // 10MB.
    //@changed_2018-02-17_14.28
    define('UPLOAD_ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES', 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif');
    // Db configs.
    define('HOST', 'localhost');
    define('PORT', 3306);
    define('DATABASE', 'bakery');
    define('USERNAME', 'root');
    define('PASSWORD', '');
    define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

    /*
     * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling, 
     * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions 
     * (mysqli_sql_exception).
     * 
     * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
     * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings. 
     * 
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
     */
    $mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
    $mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    /*
     * Create a new db connection.
     * 
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
     */
    $connection = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
    $productSaved = FALSE;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        /*
         * Read posted values.
         */
        $productName = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : '';
        $productSpecification = isset($_POST['specification']) ? $_POST['specification'] : '';
        $productCategory = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : '';
        $productSubcategory = isset($_POST['subcategory']) ? $_POST['subcategory'] : '';
        $productQuantity = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] :'';
        $productDescription = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : '';

        /*
         * Validate posted values.
         */
        if (empty($productName)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide a product title.';
        }

        if ($productQuantity == 0) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide the price.';
        }

        if (empty($productDescription)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please provide a description.';
        }

        /*
         * Create "uploads" directory if it doesn't exist.
         */
        if (!is_dir(UPLOAD_DIR)) {
            mkdir(UPLOAD_DIR, 0777, true);
        }

        /*
         * List of file names to be filled in by the upload script 
         * below and to be saved in the db table "products_images" afterwards.
         */
        $filenamesToSave = [];

        $allowedMimeTypes = explode(',', UPLOAD_ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES);

        /*
         * Upload files.
         */
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            if (isset($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
                foreach ($_FILES['file']['error'] as $uploadedFileKey => $uploadedFileError) {
                    if ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                        $errors[] = 'You did not provide any files.';
                    } elseif ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $uploadedFileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$uploadedFileKey]);

                        if ($_FILES['file']['size'][$uploadedFileKey] <= UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                            $uploadedFileType = $_FILES['file']['type'][$uploadedFileKey];
                            $uploadedFileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$uploadedFileKey];

                            $uploadedFilePath = rtrim(UPLOAD_DIR, '/') . '/' . $uploadedFileName;

                            if (in_array($uploadedFileType, $allowedMimeTypes)) {
                                if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadedFileTempName, $uploadedFilePath)) {
                                    $errors[] = 'The file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" could not be uploaded.';
                                } else {
                                    $filenamesToSave[] = $uploadedFilePath;
                                }
                            } else {
                                $errors[] = 'The extension of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" is not valid. Allowed extensions: JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF.';
                            }
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = 'The size of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" must be of max. ' . (UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1024) . ' KB';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * Save product and images.
         */
        if (!isset($errors)) {
            /*
             * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers, 
             * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the 
             * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
             * 
             * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
             */
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO products (
                        title,
                        price,
                        specification,
                        category,
                        subcategory,
                        description
                    ) VALUES (
                        ?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?
                    )';

            /*
             * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
             * 
             * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
             */
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);


            /*
             * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the 
             * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first 
             * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one 
             * or more characters which specify the types for the 
             * corresponding bind variables.
             * 
             * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
             */
            $statement->bind_param('ssssss', $productName, $productQuantity,  
                $productSpecification, $productCategory, $productSubcategory,$productDescription);

            /*
             * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
             * When executed any parameter markers which exist will 
             * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
             * 
             * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
             */
            $statement->execute();

            // Read the id of the inserted product.
            $lastInsertId = $connection->insert_id;

            /*
             * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
             * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them 
             * so that the next query can be executed.
             * 
             * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
             */
            $statement->close();
            if($statement)
            {
                header('Location: addproduct.php?success=true');
            }

            /*
             * Save a record for each uploaded file.
             */
            foreach ($filenamesToSave as $filename) {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO products_images (
                            product_id,
                            filename
                        ) VALUES (
                            ?, ?
                        )';

                $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

                $statement->bind_param('is', $lastInsertId, $filename);

                $statement->execute();

                $statement->close();
            }

            /*
             * Close the previously opened database connection.
             * 
             * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php
             */
            $connection->close();

            $productSaved = TRUE;

            /*
             * Reset the posted values, so that the default ones are now showed in the form.
             * See the "value" attribute of each html input.
             */
            $productSpecification = $productCategory =$productSubcategory=$productName = $productQuantity = $productDescription = NULL;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Means you want to add default size of image in database or somewhere else?

Comment: @RahulGupta  yes i want give default size when i insert new product

Comment: You can set a default value for a field when you define your table in SQL. The field will be given the default value whenever a row is inserted and no other value is specified for that field

Comment: @ADyson I can't understand please explain me

Comment: I mean in your CREATE TABLE statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: @ADyson I want to give default size of pixel in this code

Comment: Default size of pixel?? No idea what you mean by that sorry. Please explain in more detail. maybe give us an example

Comment: @ADyson when i insert a new product image then automatically image convert into my  default size pixel

Comment: Ah so you want to automatically resize the image file to a standard size. That's something different entirely. I thought you were talking about setting a default value for a field. So...what have you tried or researched so far? You should be able to find examples online of how to resize an image using PHP